# What are 'View Setup, Edit Setup, Delete Setup' Object Permissions?

Tags: permissions, profile, sharing, permission-sets, object

These are appearing in Profiles and Permission Sets under Object Settings - I cannot find any documentation on this - can someone please explain/elaborate?

Thanks,

Parikhit.

[image]

Comment: does the profile have `modify all` permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000010wOUAAY) with no fix.

> When using Enhanced Profile user interface and viewing a profile with Modify all Data permissions, users see extra object permissions of "edit setup, delete setup".

The workaround it proposes is to

> Disable Enhanced Profile layouts, or just ignore the two settings
> until resolution.

Since they marked it as `no fix`, I presume you're left with just ignoring it unless you want to disable the Enhanced Profile layouts.

They specifically call out the `Edit Setup` and `Delete Setup` within this known issue. I'm making an assumption, but I believe the `View Setup` is part of the same issue as there's no documented [object permission setting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.users_profiles_object_perms.htm&type=5) and it's just another variation of the `Setup` permissions that shouldn't be included within the object.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the quick response Kris.